# Can this 'how' be a fused relative?

Tags: relative-clauses

> [A] Behind the flat job figures are changes in ***how*** we live now ([The Age](http://www.theage.com.au/business/behind-the-flat-job-figures-are-changes-in-how-we-live-now-20120121-1qbbm.html))

Can’t ***how*** in above sentence have the function of the fused [free] relative? I mean, can the *how* have the meaning of ‘*the way that*’ or ‘*the way in which*’? A Korean English-grammar book says the *how* in the next sentence has the fused relative function: [B] Do it *how* you can. 
But I don’t find the explanation in CGEL, and it even says the relative word, *how*, hardly occurs in fused relatives and it is quite marginal. (CGEL,p.1076). 
So I'm confused if I can use this expression: [C] ‘*The important thing is how we live*’, intending to say ‘*The important thing is the way in which we live*’ Can I or is it only meaning ‘*The important thing is [in what way](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/how) we live*’?

Comment: I think your are right. "Do it however you can" would be better.

Comment: I would call your uses *fused relatives*, and I find this use common and acceptable (although I would agree with @ZhanlongZheng's comment). It is true however that *how* is almost never used as a ***bound*** relative, so CGEL may be defining *fused relative* more narrowly than I would.

Comment: Is it possible that this is related to CGEL's distinction between [fused relatives and interrogatives](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/124273/fused-relatives-versus-interrogatives)?

Comment: @StoneyB,In the bed last night, I remembered posting the question you’ve linked, and thought I would re-read the answer. You’ve saved my effort to search it. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In typical English usage (at least in the United States),

> The important thing is how we live

would be interpreted as meaning "The thing that matters is *the way in which* we live." How typically means "the process by which something is done," and keeps that meaning in this case.

"How" is a bit flexible grammatically. For instance, "I learned how to speak English" could be restated, "I learned *the process by which I can* speak English." At the same time, "The thing that matters is the way in which we live" could be restated, "The thing that matters is *the process by which* we live."

In the first example, "how" has a larger role, but both are correct uses.